# Supplying root password to MySQL V8 sort of fails

Tags: mysql, alter-table, password, root

On Ubuntu 20.04 I have installed MySQL V8.0.25. But I kind of fail to apply a (valid) root password. The apt-get process for installing mysql-server did not ask for a root password.
And I cannot enter mysql with the "mysql -u roor -p" command, I always do with "sudo mysql".

So i first tried with the process described by this [MySQL page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html). But this did not work at all, because V8 seems not to support the PASSWORD-function.
So instead of running

```
UPDATE mysql.user
    SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('MyNewPass'), password_expired = 'N'
    WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I used this:

```
UPDATE mysql.user 
   SET authentication_string = CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('MyNewPass'))))), password_expired = 'N' 
   WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

which I found described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60243956/edit).

The query
select host, user, authentication_string, password_expired from mysql.user;
shows a nice table:

```
   +-----------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| host      | user             | authentication_string                                                  | plugin                |
+-----------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| %         | joomla           | $A$005$MF`6ea"OfH5v1kTuRW0zJS5MKk82btugdAz62uWe6QkxnrXtTLtx5M. | caching_sha2_password |
| localhost | debian-sys-maint | $A$005$l%.r}2CBQT:+DV)a9S/UJUDJoFA8PhnCIE.E3zDFbBeUZ5vTrNSZpZDDv05 | caching_sha2_password |
| localhost | mysql.infoschema | $A$005$THISISACOMBINATIONOFINVALIDSALTANDPASSWORDTHATMUSTNEVERBRBEUSED | caching_sha2_password |
| localhost | mysql.session    | $A$005$THISISACOMBINATIONOFINVALIDSALTANDPASSWORDTHATMUSTNEVERBRBEUSED | caching_sha2_password |
| localhost | mysql.sys        | $A$005$THISISACOMBINATIONOFINVALIDSALTANDPASSWORDTHATMUSTNEVERBRBEUSED | caching_sha2_password |
s%nn69n9�NkFf7xoPdW/CCD/NjvLhTKXtx8gQmTX.RpIbOcHWsA. | caching_sha2_password |
| localhost | root             | mypass                                                                 | auth_stock            |  
+-----------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

but still "mysql -u root -p" does not work with the suppiel password.
I still get message:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I also tried this - without any success:

```
UPDATE mysql.user 
   SET authentication_string = 'mypass', password_expired = 'N', plugin = '' 
   WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
```

The ALTER cmd did not work

neither

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'oldpass';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'
```

nor

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'oldpass' REPLACE 'mypass';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'
```

I spent now many hours in this and have no clue how to preceed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I had learned about "plugins" only a few hours ago. Had asked this question at "stackoverflow" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67608533/supplying-root-password-to-mysql-v8-sort-of-fails#autocomment119514484) before when I was asked to put it here.

Comment: if you are working with Joomla, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1 :** Add below parameter in `my.cnf` file under `[mysqld]` section.

`skip-grant-tables`

**Step 2 :**  Restart MySQL instance.

**Step 3 :** Login MySQL instance. (This will not ask you password)

`mysql -uroot -p`

**Step 4 :** Reset root password.

`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewRoot@123Pass';`

**Step 5 :** Remove `skip-grant-tables` parameter from `my.cnf` file & restart MySQL instance.

**Step 6 :** Now Login MySQL instance using `root` user & new password.

Comment: Sorry couldn't get to this earlier. I tried and get this message when issuing the ALTER USER-cmd: ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

Comment: Have you tried creating new user in skip-grant-tables mode ?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` is unnecessary.  (If it is necessary, something else is going wrong.)

Do not use that `UPDATE` with 8.0, only use `GRANT` and associated commands.

Note that using "passwords" out of fashion in 8.0 unless you specify that the user is using `native_passwords`.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get what you mean. When is sudo unnecessary? In the "sudo mysql" command? How can I issue commands with root privilege when not being authenticated as "root"? And the question her is, how can I authenticate as root.

Comment: The OS "root" is distinct from the mysql "root".  (OK, 8.0 has a way to tie them together; did you do that?)

Comment: I'm aware, that both of the roots are different. My OS-root even does not have the name "root". And I occasionally found that the "sudo mysql" worked - for whatever reason I cannot tell - when "mysql -u -root -p" didn't.

Comment: Aside from installing, users should not need to know anything about the "user" involved in the installation of "mysql" (mysqld, mysql, mysqldump, etc).  And normally all users can execute `mysql` without anything like "sudo".

Answer (score 0):

Gave up about this issue. Reinstalled the whole system and used MariaDB instead of MySQL. For this installation all worked fine and the root-user has got now a password.